# NGINX Proxy does not work

Tags: docker, nginx, digital-ocean

I have two containers running on my DigitalOcean droplet. The first container is a REST api container running on port 9090. The second container is a ReactJS multistage container with Nginx running on port 4500. The docker-compose file is this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    ubgrillmysql:
        image: mysql:5.6
        container_name: ubgrillmysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=finder
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=ubgrillData
            - MYSQL_USER=ubgadmin
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=win(der90)Admin
        volumes:
            - /home/justicar/workspace/applications/data
        networks:
            - ubgrill_network
    web:
        image: ubgrill/web 
        container_name: web
        depends_on:
            - ubgrillmysql
        environment:
            - DATABASE_HOST=ubgrillmysql
            - DATABASE_USER=ubgadmin
            - DATABASE_PASSWORD=win(der90)Admin
            - DATABASE_NAME=ubgrillData
            - DATABASE_PORT=3306
        ports:
            - 9090:9090
        networks:
            - ubgrill_network
    frontend:
        image: ubgrill/frontend
        container_name: frontend
        build: ./src/main/ubgrill
        depends_on:
            - web
        ports:
            - 4500:80
        networks:
            - ubgrill_network

networks:
    ubgrill_network:
        external:
```

I have installed nginx on my droplet as I intend to transfer my blog there in the future. I created a server block using mu droplet's domain name and stored in /etc/nginx/sites-available with the name `<domain>.com`. The file is as follows:

```
upstream ubgrillapi{
    server localhost:9090;
}

upstream ubgrillapp{
    server localhost:4500;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/<domain>.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name <domain>.com www.<domain>.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /ubgrill/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://ubgrillapi;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /ubgrill/app/ {
        proxy_pass http://ubgrillapp;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
     }
}
```

When I try to access, `http://<domain>.com/ubgrill/app`, I get a 404(Not Found) error. The same goes for `http://<domain>.com/ubgrill/api`. I can access the app at `http://<domain>.com:4500` and the api at `http://<domain>.com:9090/ubgrill/api` (*The API actually starts with /ubgrill/api*). I am a complete noob in nginx proxy and the tutorials online all deal with nginx in a separate container which is not my configuration. What is the problem with my configuration and can you please point me to a more comprehensive tutorial on nginx? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In nginx conf :

> proxy_pass http://ubgrillapp;

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Nginx proxy_pass shows the location

```
location / {
proxy_pass       http://localhost:8000;
proxy_set_header Host      $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

(http://example.com:9090/ubgrill/api)

In your case you i guess you should set this to:

```
proxy_pass localhost:9090/ubgrill/api
```

Comment: That does not work. Still gives me a 404 Not Found Error.